# How to model repeated measurements for two different scenarios?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures

I have a large pool of electronic devices. The devices are of the same kind and each was measured before and after an irradiation.
Measurement means the following: Increase the voltage step by step and observe the current for that actual voltage. The data is not balanced (neither before nor after the radiation. As well as for one single device as for all devices). The irradiation is almost the same since the irradiation time and dose was almost the same.
Furthermore the measurement procedure changed slightly over the years (e.g. in case of used measurement devices and the process itself) but the measurement is in detail unknown since an external lab did that.

Up to know all I know is that there are changes. Apparently not that large (I just compared histograms for the differences in voltages and amplifications) but I would like to have a look closer on it. How can I do that?

I think it is very similar to the following case:
Imagine a class and you want to study the class' behaviour for two teachers. Probably for the same subject(?!).
Is that assumption or simplification correct? And how do I apply this?
I guess a linear mixed model is suitable for that?

A measurement of one single device but I guess the explicit curve is meaningless in the context:

[image: One single device before and after irradiation]

Comment: what do you mean with "the data is not balanced"? Do you mean that [the design is not balanced](http://www.statisticshowto.com/balanced-and-unbalanced-designs/)? In other words, different electronic devices have different sample sizes. For example, device 3 has 245 (Voltage, Amplification) data points, while device 5 has 417 (Voltage, Amplification) data points. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Adding the plot was a great idea in my opinion. Do you have multiple curves for the same device? Or strictly one curve for device?

Comment: @DeltaIV Thanks for the attention and help! Yes, that's right. The data is unbalanced in this way: The devices have different measurement sample sizes. Also one specific device has a different sample size in case of the measurement before and after the irradiation.

There are two curves (one before and one after irradiation). I'll add the second one for that device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here there are repeated measures within devices. A mixed effects model, with random intercepts for devices and fixed effects for voltage and each scenario would be appropriate here. There is an obvious non-linear association that should also be modelled perhaps with a log-transformation.

Comment: @Ben does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer, or if not please let us know why ?